# Can't get ads from prebid.js after updating params

Tags: prebid.js

I am using prebidjs, using the example jsfiddle to test some parameters received from a few bidders. Strange thing is, I have some params for IndexExchange that work just fine, but I just got some new parameters and, with those params, it stops returning any bids. 
I am thinking that this is a problem with the IDs (parameters) submitted to us.

Index Exchange requires the "site id" param as follow:

```
 bidder: 'indexExchange',
             params: {
                id: "27",
                siteID: "178062"
           }
```

What could the problem be if a change of the `siteID` makes the difference between a successful bid and just getting a

> No bids or error response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you supply a wrong `siteID` and `IndexExchange` can't find demand for the ID passed - not surprising if the ID is wrong. Just reach out your partners to ensure ID validity

Comment: yes, that was the issue. 
the partner had not set the inventory live.

Thanks